# Derivative of a function of several variables using chain rule.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f : \mathbb R^ 2 \to \mathbb R $ be differentiable such that $f (1, 1) = 1$, $f_x (1, 1) = 2$ and $f_y (1, 1) = 5$. 
If $g(x) = f (x, f (x, x))$, $\forall$ $x \in \mathbb R$, determine $g'(1)$.

My solution goes like this:

Let $f(x,x)=$ $y$ and $X=$ $(x,y)$. Then,

$g'(x)=$ $(D_1f(X),D_2f(X))\cdot(\delta x/\delta x,\delta y/\delta x)$ . At $x=$ $1$, $y=$ $f(x,x)=$ $1$, $D_1f(X)=$ $2$, and $\delta y/\delta x=$ $2$. Taking $y=$ $f (x, x)$, the partial derivative of $f(x,f(x,x))$ with respect to $y$ gives $D_2f(X)=$ $5$ at $(1,1)$.

Therefore, $g'(1)=$ $(2,5)\cdot(1,2)=$ $12$

Somehow, the solution seems shaky. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Put $v(t)=f(\gamma(t))$, whete $\gamma(t)=(t,t)$. Hence, $v'(t)=\langle\nabla f(\gamma(t)),\gamma'(t)\rangle=\langle\nabla f(\gamma(t)),(1,1)\rangle=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t,t)+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(t,t)$. On the other hand, $g(t)=f(\beta(t))$, where $\beta(t)=(t,f(t,t))=(t,f(\gamma(t)))=(t,v(t))$. Thus, $g'(t)=\langle\nabla f(\beta(t)),\beta'(t)\rangle=\langle\nabla f(\beta(t)),(1,v'(t))\rangle=\left\langle\left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(\beta(t)),\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(\beta(t))\right),(1,v'(t))\right\rangle$. Then,
$g'(1)=\left\langle\left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(\beta(1)),\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(\beta(1))\right),(1,v'(1))\right\rangle=\left\langle\left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(1,1),\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(1,1)\right),\left(1,\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(1,1)+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(1,1)\right)\right\rangle=\left\langle\left(2,5\right),\left(1,2+5\right)\right\rangle=\left\langle\left(2,5\right),\left(1,7\right)\right\rangle=2+35=37.$

Comment: Junior: Great answer! Thanks a ton...